# String seeming to be one single space character, but isn't

Tags: r, string, rvest

I'm doing some web scraping using `rvest` and I've come across something odd.  There's a string that looks like `" "` but isn't.  I've reproduced this on two computers, a Mac OSX system running R 3.6.3 and a Windows 10 system running R 3.6.3.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
# scrape website, no issue
webpage <- rvest::read_html("https://www.usms.org/longdist/ldnats00/1hrf4044.php")
html <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, css = "td")
results <- rvest::html_text(html)
# cleaning results a bit, no issue
results <- stringr::str_replace(results, "\\\r\\\n", "")
results <- results[results != ""]
# the mystery string
results[605]
[1] " "
```

If I compare `results[605]` with `" "`, or with the copy-and-pasted result of printing `results[605]`

```
results[605] == " "
[1] FALSE
```

If I store `results[605]` in a value

```
string_605 <- results[605]
string_605
[1] " "
results[605] == string_605
[1] TRUE
string_605 == " "
[1] FALSE
```

Just as a sanity check

```
" " == " "
[1] TRUE
```

What is this mystery string and how do I match it?  I'd like to get rid of it like `results <- results[results != mystery string]`

Comment: Probably the problem is  the backslash.

Comment: Maybe tab? `\t`

Comment: Not a tab either as `str_detect(results[605], "\\t")`  returns `FALSE` although interestingly `str_detect(results[605], "\\s")` returns `TRUE` so it is some kind of whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string here is `<U+00A0>`

My solution is always try to `clipr::write_clip(results[605])` and paste into whatever place. Then you can see the code of this string also can paste into google to search it :)

After you can do this `results <- results[results != '\U00A0']`

Comment: `clipr::write_clip(results[605])` does work, but how did you figure out the character was called '\U00A0'?  When I paste the results of `write_clip` I get what looks to be a space, but it does match `results[605]`

Comment: Frank didn't say because it's against SO policy to provide links to external websites. https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html